# vuex module axios in vue3 composition api

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex, dispatch, vue-composition-api

I am new to vue and working with vue 3 and the composition API. It is really hard to find stuff related to the composition API, so I try to get help here. I am using axios in combination with vuex modules for consuming APIs.

How can I transfere this code from options API to composition API?

TestApi.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
const posts = {
namespaced: true,
state: {
    posts: []
},
mutations: {
    SET_POSTS(state, data){
        state.posts = data
    }
},
actions: {
    loadPosts({commit}) {
        axios
            .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .then( res => {
                commit('SET_POSTS', res.data)
            } )
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }
},
getters: {
    getPosts(state){
        return state.posts
    }
}
}
export default posts
```

App.vue

```html
<template>
<div class="post" v-for="post in getPosts" :key="post.id">
    
      <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
      <p>{{ post.body }}</p>

  </div>
</template>

<script>

import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import { computed } from 'vue'


export default {
  computed: {
  ...mapGetters('posts', ['getPosts'])
  },
  created(){
  this.$store.dispatch('posts/loadPosts')
  }
}

</script>

<style>
  .post{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
</style>
```

I tried something like this. But it does not work:

```html
import { useStore } from 'vuex'
import { computed } from 'vue'

export default {
    setup(){
      getData();
      const store = useStore()
      function getData(){
        store.dispatch('posts/loadPosts');
      }
      const getPosts = computed(() => store.getters['getPosts'])
      return{ getPosts }
   }
}
```

Error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoul run the function after initializing the store :

```
    setup(){
      
      const store = useStore()
       getData();
 ...
```